# awk to improve format from un-formatted inputs

Tags: unix, awk

Would like to know how to improve below un-formatted inputs into formatted Output.
Am able to do this by following  steps ...
Actual input files contains 18 fields.

$ cat st_Input.txt

```
Total No. of Records Displayed: 4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Circle Desc.|Serial From        |Serial To          |        Quantity|Plant Desc.  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   CCCC        |20282783701        |20282788700        |      5,000.000 |2220         |
|   CCCC        |5991421000742062451|5991421000742062477|         27.000 |2310         |
|   CCCC        |41700000906        |41700011005        |     10,100.000 |2210         |
|   CCCC        |5988888000742062478|5988888000742062564|         10.000 |2210         |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  *            |                   |                   |      15,724.000|             |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Step#1 : Formatting field separator `from "|"to ","` to avoid field position changes , example Qty `5,000.000 will be changed as 5000.000 instead of 5 and 000.000`

Command#1:

```
awk -F '|' '{ gsub(/,/,""); $1=$1 }1' OFS="," st_Input.txt >Format_st_Input.txt
```

Output#1:

```
Total No. of Records Displayed: 4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
,   Circle Desc.,Serial From        ,Serial To          ,        Quantity,Plant Desc.  , 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
,   CCCC        ,20282783701        ,20282788700        ,      5000.000 ,2220         ,
,   CCCC        ,5991421000742062451,5991421000742062477,         27.000 ,2310         ,
```

Step#2 : Have tried below commnd

IF field `$3~"5991421000"` print to "Op22_st_Input.txt" and `$3~"[0-9]"` print to "Op33_st_Input.txt" and all `other junk characters into` "Op44_st_Input.txt"

Command#2:

```
awk -F"," '{OFS=","; if ($3~"5991421000") {print $0,FILENAME > "Op22_st_Input.txt";next} \
else if ($3~"[0-9]"){print $0,FILENAME > "Op33_st_Input.txt";next} \
else {print $0,FILENAME > "Op44_st_Input.txt";next}}' Format_st_Input.txt
```

Is there any easiest way to change the field position from `Delete $1, $2==$3,$3==$4 then print all` the remaining field items
instead of typing  `print $2,$3,$4,... till $18` and avoid many steps to be followed

Desired Output for # Op22_st_Input.txt

```
5991421000742062451,5991421000742062477,   CCCC        ,         27.000 ,2310         ,,Format_st_Input.txt
```

Desired Output for # Op33_st_Input.txt

```
20282783701        ,20282788700        ,   CCCC        ,      5000.000 ,2220         ,,Format_st_Input.txt
41700000906        ,41700011005        ,   CCCC        ,     10100.000 ,2210         ,,Format_st_Input.txt
5988888000742062478,5988888000742062564,   CCCC        ,         10.000 ,2210         ,,Format_st_Input.txt
```

Desired Output for # Op44_st_Input.txt

```
Total No. of Records Displayed: 4,Format_st_Input.txt
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------,Format_st_Input.txt
,   Circle Desc.,Serial From        ,Serial To          ,        Quantity,Plant Desc.  , ,Format_st_Input.txt
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------,Format_st_Input.txt
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------,Format_st_Input.txt
,  *            ,                   ,                   ,      15724.000,             , ,Format_st_Input.txt
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------,Format_st_Input.txt
```

Comment: a) I can help you do this. b) I am not going to help you do this. I suspect many others will feel the same way because when we see massive lines of input and a bunch of complicated information on how you think the problem should be approached it's discouraging enough to make people just move on to the next question. Show some small, REPRESENTATIVE input, and expected output that given an answer you could build upon to solve your full problem. And you STILL have the same rookie mistakes in your scripts I mentioned previously.

Comment: You are attempting to break this problem down to a series of separate commands. When you find yourself doing this and operating on the same information, it is probably time to combine all the commands into an `awk script`. This allows quite a bit of flexibility in handling the data because of the temporary storage available that prevents having to re-read and re-parse the information. Alternatively, you can accomplish the reformatting by reading the information into array variables in a bash script. The point being, read once, reformat as required.

Comment: Ed Morton, sorry , i have reduced the I/O samples to min fields , basically am finance background person not from programming background,some times it is difficult to understand the code & how and where to change the command that's why pasted all 18 fields, will avoid this in future...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ca use this awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
    {of=""}
    $3~/[0-9]/{of="Op33_st_Input.txt"} 
    $3~/5991421000/{of="Op22_st_Input.txt"}
    of{s=$2;$2=$3;$3=$4;$4=s;$1=""; print substr($0,2),FILENAME > of; next}
    {print $0, FILENAME > "Op44_st_Input.txt"}' Format_st_Input.txt
```

#### Explanation:

- `BEGIN` section sets field separator and output field separator as comma
- initialize `of` variable to empty string for each line
- if `$3` matches regex `[0-9]` then set of to `Op33_st_Input.txt`
- if `$3` matches regex `5991421000` then set of to `Op22_st_Input.txt`
- if `of` is set then use formatted output and redirect to variable `of`
- otherwise print line, FILENAME to `Op44_st_Input.txt`

Comment: Anubhava, Thanks a lot, it is working as expected , Could you please add some comments to understand better !!!

Comment: Glad it worked out. I am using Mobile at present, will add an explanation when I get back to my computer in few hours.

Comment: Anubhava, Ok, my actual input file contains $18 fields , Serial From -$11 and Serial To -$12 , 
    hence print would be  $11, $12, $2, $3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18 OFS FILENAME : 
    Just for curiosity, is there any short form print $2-$10,$13-$8

Comment: Ok I added an explanation and updated `awk` command to print full line smartly so that you can avoid printing each individual field.

Comment: Anubhava, Checked the script , it is working fine with all 18 fields , seems substr($0,2) taken care by all the remaining fields to print, how does that magic, kindly provide some in-sight if you get some time ;)

Comment: `substr($0, 2)` just prints whole line starting from 2nd character onwards. `$0` has already been altered by `s=$2;$2=$3;$3=$4;$4=s;$1="";` which is basically removing `$1`. Setting `$3` value to `$2`, `$4` to `$3` and `$4` to `$2`. Took me some time build this logic by looking at your well drafted question many times :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't.  Use `cut`:

```
cut -d , -f 11,12,2-10,13-17
```